# Why does it take so long to Quit?

Tags: performance-tuning

Running `Quit` is a core task repeated many times in any debugging/development cycle. Its efficiency is therefore important and yet in my set-up it is taking somewhere between 4-10s to complete. This seems excessive. Why is it taking so long and what strategies can be employed to minimise this time?

I've observed the lower bound of 4s for a "clean" `Quit`, 8s when all my "init" packages are loaded and sometimes >10s following a long session. I also wonder by how much this varies from system-to-system and/or version-to-version? (timings above for V12.1.1, 2018 MacBook Pro, macOS 10.15.6).

**Update**
As a benchmark to keep tabs on this timing, the following shows Launch and `Quit` times (in seconds) for both "Clean" (no packages loaded, no other notebooks open) and "PackagesLoaded" scenarios.

[image]

Hence the resolution of the above shows that the time to `Quit` is actually pretty consistent and reasonable irrespective of current state. Hence, anything beyond a 0.5s `Quit` time suggests an issue or perhaps is an indication that  an automatic kernel has re-launched for some reason, possibly as catalogued in my answer.

Comment: It probably comes from closing down threads, calling destructors, freeing resources etc. I do not work at Wolfram but based on my C++ experience I imagine it spends a lot of time closing things down and freeing memory. Since the kernel executable process ends on `Quit[]` anyway, there is little point to this - the OS will free that stuff much faster in bulk. The saying goes _"don't clean the dishes as the building is being demolished"_. However, design-wise it's probably hard to avoid because calling destructors is also necessary to prevent memory leaks while the kernel is up and running.

Comment: I'm on 12.1.1.0 Windows 10 and I have to say I haven't noticed it go above 2s with both Rubi and Combinatorica loaded. Sometimes I haven't been able to quit the kernel at all this way because the front-end is locked up and no longer interactive, so I open the task manager and kill the Wolfram Kernel subprocess of Mathematica.exe directly - this is instantaneous and kills the kernel while keeping the front-end alive.

Comment: @flinty *"don't clean the dishes as the building is being demolished"* is a good way of putting my initial thoughts but I don't get the last sentence suggesting the dishes still needed cleaning? I guess the task-manager-kills not having any deleterious effects suggest the cleaning was not necessary? Also, can I ask, any noticeable difference between `Quit`s having those two packages (un)loaded?

Comment: Yes, cleaning is not always necessary at termination - the OS will handle it, except in some ambiguous cases like closing ports / file locks. Freeing-resources is necessary during a program session though, so programmers will design for that case and this worsens termination performance. I'd have to profile a WolframKernel process during a quit to determine if this was the cause by looking for lots of hits on name-mangled C++ destructors. I cannot see any difference with those packages loaded / unloaded. If you have Apple's 'Instruments' installed you could profile it.

Comment: Perhaps you could share your init.m ? And how long does `Quit[]` take if your init.m is empty and you start from a blank notebook?

Comment: Do you get the slow quit if you do Evaluation > Quit Kernel, vs the `Quit[]` command ? If not, then see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67098/72682) which suggests to me you may still have something running in the evaluation queue.

Comment: Viewing my init.m probably wouldn't be that illuminating as it's a bit elaborate (50+ packages, linked to multiple subpackage and "DeclarePackage variables" in the hundreds. This complexity might suggest the higher timings (I may have to do some fine-grained testing) but on the other hand the lazy loading it pervasively implements should reduce the loading memory footprint while the "clean" Quit of 4s I mentioned is from a blank notebook without any init.m/Dynamics/$Epilog etc.

Comment: Yes, the menu Quit still seems slow (although harder to time) but what I've just noticed is that post-Quit evaluations are quick suggesting that my Quit is somehow also re-starting a kernel explaining the 2s doubling. Also, my "init" loading is being done by an `$InitializationContexts` setting. Look I'll stop now and I'd better go and try a few more things - thanks for your input -  it has given me some ideas to test.

Answer (score 9):

There are conceivably numerous explanations but the immediate reason that (mostly) prompted this question took some tracking down so I'll record it here:

## 1. Setting of "ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit" option

I had inadvertently left this (undocumented) option set to

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession,"ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit"] = False
```

when tinkering with the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82804/2249) to the question of how to [Quit the Kernel and start new session automatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82803/quit-the-kernel-and-start-new-session-automatically/82804#82804). The question involved doing this automatic re-starting via a button and hence the answer's `False` setting of this option was only temporary. Hence that answer shouldn't introduce the *persistent* `False` setting above that caused this behaviour.

With this option set to `False` the 4s `Quit` time involves a new kernel restarting. With it returned to the default `True` a "clean" `Quit`takes a more familiar ~0.5s with subsequent "clean" launches a more familiar ~1s.

## 2. A setting in $UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd/init.m

This is where `"ClearEvaluationQueueOnKernelQuit"` is stored which might be non-obvious when hunting for kernel issues (it doesn't, for example, appear on any of `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd,AutoloadPath]`). It also contains a lot of settings that build-up over time some of which may be candidates for causing any excessive timings.

## 3. A Dynamic in some open notebook

These can quietly launch kernels after `Quit` is run making the `Quit` time seem longer than it actually is.

Comment: I'm glad you finally got to the bottom of it and posted this.

Comment: @flinty So am I! You were right to suspect the evaluation queue which may have triggered a memory for tracking this down. Thanks. It turns out then, that no great "dish-cleaning" actually does take place in a `Quit` but the other take-away is a bit more galling -- programmers really ought to practice good coding hygiene when tinkering by re-setting default values - *especially* when they involve non-documented features and *especially* when they occur in non-normal control flows!